# public Class<?>[] scriptLibraryReturnColumnTypes()

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public Class<?>[] scriptLibraryReturnColumnTypes()
{
   return QueryResultViewHelper.getClasses();
}
```

I would want to know what to they mean by Class[]

Comment: It is an array of `Class` objects. See `Object`'s `.getClass()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [fge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1093528/fge) said, there exist a class called "**Class**". That sound a little bit confusing, but just take it as it is for the moment. It's a class with name "**Class**".

The notation `[]` refers to an array. An array is something like a list (to make it simple). So `Class[]` means an array of objects of the type `Class`.

Here's a simpler example:

```
public Person<>[] getListOfPersons() {
...
}
```

This method would return an array (`[]`) of `Person` objects. `Person` is the class/type of the objects in the array. Just replace `Person` with `Class`.